# C# Xml Parsing from StringBuilder

Tags: c#, xml, stringbuilder

I have a StringBuilder with the contents of an XML file. Inside the XML file is a root tag called `<root>` and contains multiple `<node>` tags.

I'd like to parse through the XML to read values of tags within in s, but not sure how to do it.

Will I have to use some C# XML data type for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder (xml);

TextReader textReader = new StringReader (sb.ToString ());
XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load (textReader);

var nodeValueList = from node in xmlDocument.Descendants ("node")
                    select node.Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

**You should use  classes available in either [`System.Xml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.aspx) or [`System.Xml.Linq`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299195.aspx) to parse XML.**

[`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument_members.aspx) is part of the LINQ extensions for XML and is particularly easy to use if you need to parse through an arbitrary structure. I would suggest using it rather than `XmlDocument` (unless you have legacy code or are not on .NET 3.5).

**Creating an `XDocument` from a `StringBuilder` is straightforward:**

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse( stringBuilder.ToString() );
```

From here, you can use `FirstNode`, `Descendents()`, and the many other properties and methods available to walk and examine the XML structure. And since `XDocument` is designed to work well with LINQ, you can also write queries like:

```
var someData = from node in doc.Descendants ("yourNodeType")
               select node.Value; // etc..
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking the specifically named nodes then you don't need to load the document into memory, you can process it yourself with an XmlReader.

```
using(var sr = new StringReader(stringBuilder.ToString)) {
  using(var xr = XmlReader.Create(sr)) {
    while(xr.Read()) {
      if(xr.IsStartElement() && xr.LocalName == "node")
        xr.ReadElementString(); //Do something here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is way more efficient than above methods. Almost zero memory footprint. Awesome!!.

Answer (score 0):

use XDocument.Parse(...)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I suggest you use an [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) object to parse the content of your string.
Here is an example who print all inner text contained in your  tags:

```
var doc=new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(stringBuilder.TosTring());
XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("node");
for (int i=0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
{   
  XmlNode node=elemList[i];
  Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
}
```

using Node object members, you can also easily extract all you  attributes .

Comment: using LoadXml is very memory in-efficient. It's memory footprint is too high (almost 10x times to normal xml footprint). The user just want to read the data so we can do it without loading to memory.

Answer (score 0):

There are several objects at your disposal for working with XML. Look at the `System.Xml` namespace for objects such as `XmlDocument` as well as the `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter` families of objects. If using C# 3.0+, look at the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace and the `XDocument` class.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to read all the values in the XML file , you could look into deserializing the XML into a C# data Object.

[Deserializing XML into class obj in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770160/deserializing-xml-into-class-obj-in-c)